# Pandas read .csv and set index column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when I read a .csv and  set the 'Column A' as index column.

```
df = pd.read_csv(index_col = 'Column A')
print(df.colums)
```

However, I cannot access 'Column A' anymore. I still want to use it as one column to access its date.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you can access it with `df.index`.

Comment: Please explain specifically how you want to access it. There are many index operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this is very straightforward: just setting index as a column.

```
df['index1'] = df.index
```

Comment: This seems redundant. Why set it as index and keep as column? A fuller background of your broad question would help us understand your [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 9):

This will do the trick, simple and clean:

```
df = pd.read_csv().set_index('Column A')
```